# How to stop Java web app on server remotely

Tags: tomcat, java, sql, vnc

I remotely ran a Java web application on a server using TightVNC. One of the tasks of the web app was that it would schedule and do a specific task every 15 minutes. Turns out the code is incorrect and produces a SQL Exception: Invalid column index ever 15 minutes.

Basically I'm trying to kill the version of the web app running on the server and run an old one. Normally I would use kill -9 *PID* and then run the older version. However no comman on TightVNC seems to do anything. If I type clear and press enter nothing happens so I just have a growing list of the Invalid column index errors. If I type kill -9 *PID* or any other comman then when I press enter the cursor just moves to the next line to no affect.

Anybody Know how I can stop this so I can revert back to the old version of the web app?

Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are not typing in your shell's prompt but on STDIN of a running application in your shell that does happily ignore your input. You could try to CTRL-C or CTRL-Z this application -- or open another shell ...